# Using a user-defined distance metric for k-nn in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sklearn.neighbors as ng 

def mydist(x, y):
    return np.sum((x-y)**2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nn = ng.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree',metric='mydist')
```

I am using sci-kit learn 0.18.1 and I get this error

```
ValueError: Metric 'mydist' not valid for algorithm 'ball_tree'
```

I also tried using algorithm = 'brute' but the error persists.

What is causing this? How do I use an user defined distance metric correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of valid metrics for the `ball_tree` algorithm - `scikit-learn` checks internally that the specified metric is among them:

```
In [114]: from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

In [115]: BallTree.valid_metrics
Out[115]:
['euclidean',
 'l2',
 'minkowski',
 'p',
 'manhattan',
 'cityblock',
 'l1',
 'chebyshev',
 'infinity',
 'seuclidean',
 'mahalanobis',
 'wminkowski',
 'hamming',
 'canberra',
 'braycurtis',
 'matching',
 'jaccard',
 'dice',
 'kulsinski',
 'rogerstanimoto',
 'russellrao',
 'sokalmichener',
 'sokalsneath',
 'haversine',
 'pyfunc']       # <--- NOTE
```

so try to specify `metric='pyfunc'` and `metric_params={"func":mydist}`:

```
knn = ng.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree',
                              metric='pyfunc', metric_params={"func":mydist})
```